# How can I take inputs with hidden input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to take an `input` when a `button` is pressed that is if I press a `button` it should focus itself to the `input` box. But I don't want that the actual input to be displayed on the screen or rather the actual `input` box.
So far I have tried this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let Button = document.createElement('button');
  let TxtB = document.createTextNode('Button');
  let Btn = document.createElement('button');
  let TxtAdd = document.createTextNode('Btn');
  let Input = document.createElement('Input');
  $(Button).append(TxtB);
  $(Btn).append(TxtAdd);
  $(Input).attr('type', 'hidden');
  $(Button).bind("click", function() {
    Input.focus();
  })
  $(Btn).bind("click", function() {
    console.log(Input.value);
  })
  $(document.body).append(Button);
  $(document.body).append(Input);
  $(document.body).append(Btn);
})
```

This code gives a `null` value no matter what I enter.

Comment: if it's supposed to be hidden, why are you trying to focus on it?

Comment: Ofcourse it returns null, because you never set a value to the input element.

Comment: Wait what? focusing a hidden input? is that even a thing? did you expect it to focus and let you type into it?

Comment: Maybe you should be using `.hide()` and `.show()`, so you show the text box when the user clicks the button, and the user can then enter something into it.

Comment: You won't be able to use focus or write directly to it without some middleware and even then, for an interface that is supposed to be user-friendly, updating an element that they don't know they're updating is not user-friendly.  You need to better describe your issue.  This sounds like an A-B problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to show the input control but hide the value it contains. if that is the case then try :

```
$(Input).attr('type', 'password');
```

instead of :

```
 $(Input).attr('type', 'hidden');
```